# Silverlight does not work in develop

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I have an silverlight application written in c# in vs13.

The application worked awsome on my 32bit computer, but when i try to operate it in my 64bit computer there was a fatal error.

The problem is that when i start the prgram i check if "window.silverlight.hasinstalled" but the window object does not even have a silvrrligt property.

What even more strange is that when I open othe silverlight website and i check the window object in the console its contain the silverlight property..  any ideas?
Thank a lot?

Answer (score 0):

Not all browser versions support 64-bit Silverlight. See [Compatible Operating Systems and Browsers](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx#sysreq) for details.
To make things worse, even using a browser that does support it, you won't be able to debug your application as it is not supported for x64.